# "have a worry of"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

> Whether there’s a worry of looking ignorant or potentially costing themselves some leverage (and at the same time, money), a car owners’ inability to ask for help could end up costing them in the long run. ([source](https://www.mccluskeychevrolet.com/blog/oil-tires-and-more-car-service-faqs/))
>
> Through the clean cosmetics, there is never a worry of looking like I have too much makeup on or that my pores will clog. ([source](https://ginamarieproducts.com/zoe-bruni-women-inspiring-women/))
>
> I have a worry of sounding like a beginner. ([source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/worry-for-or-worry-about-the-delay.1298284/))

I have never heard "a worry of". I would have used "over" or "about" in these sentences. Does "have a worry of looking stupid" sound natural and idiomatic to people?

Comment: It sounds like a Britishism to me, but it is perfectly understandable, being a parallel to idiomatic usages such as "have a fear of".

Comment: "a fear of" was also the first thing called to mind. That's why I actually thought "have a worry of" was a mistake.

Comment: That should be *owner's,* because it's singular.